# Why is my Django custom validator failing?

Tags: django, validation, django-admin, many-to-many

I am trying to design a model that allows me to schedule events (softball games) and create game rosters from a larger team roster:

```
class Game(models.Model):
DateTime = models.DateTimeField()
opponent = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default="TBD")
players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, limit_choices_to={'id__in': Player.objects.filter(active='True')},blank=True)
```

So far so good. But I also want to add some custom validation to the players ManyToMany field so that the game roster conforms with league rules about minimum and maximum roster sizes, among other things.

When I call the following clean() method I get a ValueError returned ('Game' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.):

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    #self.save()
    players_count = self.players.count()
    # Don't allow rosters with fewer than 9 players
    if players_count < 9:
        raise ValidationError('Rosters must have at least 9 players')
```

If I insert the self.save that's commented out, the validator works, but I end up with multiple entries of the game.

I'm new to this - it's my first non-tutorial Django project - so I'm guessing there's a fairly simple answer. I've poked around here and the Django documentation and tried some things that looked promising, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the clean method you just want to do the validation check. So, saving it would be a bad idea in the first place. So, from the form object you can get the value for the players field and run the validation on it. Do remember to return the cleaned_data when you are overriding the form clean method.

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    players = self.cleaned_data.get('players', [])
    players_count = len(players):
    # Don't allow rosters with fewer than 9 players
    if players_count < 9:
        raise ValidationError('Rosters must have at least 9 players')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work for me. Got AtrributeError:'Game' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: Figured it out. This answer essentially works, but I had not created a new form class to handle it.